# Cache images offscreen in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, caching, css, mobile-safari

I have an javascript image gallery that slides in images from offscreen in Mobile Safari.  It seems like the offscreen images are not getting cached because every time they slide in it takes a few seconds to load them at which point they are already halfway to their destination.  I'm trying to get all the images to load during the initial page load.  It seems Mobile Safari ignores or "garbage collects" offscreen images.  Is there a way through CSS3 (some -webkit prefix property) or any way so that all images load and stay loaded so their is no flickering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the set of images in the gallery is somewhat static (ie. it's managed through some sort of upload process rather than picking up images dynamically), you could try using an HTML5 offline application cache for your images.  [This blog post describes the technique](http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/), along with some other pitfalls frequently encountered with iPhone caching.